# After redirecting my banner is not being shown

Tags: css, .htaccess

```
<div id="background"></div>
<style>
    #background{
        background-image: url('/banner.png');
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

So this is my construction file that I want to show everyone going to my website here is my htaccess

```
Options ALL -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=1.3.3.7
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/construction.php
RewriteRule .* /construction.php [L]
```

I'm not using my IP yet since I want to test it out how would it look for people visiting my website.

The site loads properly and the path to the image is alright but the site is still blank.

Comment: You are redirecting _everything_ to your `/construction.php` file internally, and that includes the request for `/banner.png`. So you will either have to make your php script handle that request as well (and have it serve up the image data) – or be more specific in what requests you want to rewrite, and which ones you don’t (f.e. by adding another `RewriteCond` that checks the request URI for being `/banner.png`, same as you are already doing for the PHP script.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without rewrite for images:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=1.3.3.7
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/construction.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /construction.php [L]
```